# GUI Calculator - ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Hi I have created a graphical calculator using Python 3.4 and it works up until I attempt to enter an add or subtract function using the add and subtract buttons. I recieve the following error:

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
```

I understand that the error is in relation to converting input into an integer but i cannot work out the answer! Thanks in advance.

```
import sys
from tkinter import*


total= 0
temp= 0
temp2= 0
unisymbol=' '



def equalparttwo():
    global total
    global temp
    global temp2
    global unisymbol

    if unisymbol== 'minus' :
        temp2=int(textoutput.get())
        total=temp-temp2
        textoutput.delete(0,END)
        textoutput.insert(END,total)
    elif unisymbol=='plus':
        temp2=int(textoutput.get())
        total=temp + textoutput.get()
        textoutput.delete(0,END)
        textoutput.insert(END,total)

def add():
    global temp
    global unisymbol
    temp=int(textoutput.get())
    unisymbol='plus'
    textoutput.delete(0,END)

def sub():
    global temp
    global unisymbol
    temp=int(textoutput.get())
    unisymbol='minus'
    textoutput.delete(0,END)

def equal():
    global temp2
    temp2=int(textoutput.get())
    textoutput.delete(0,END)
    equalparttwo()


def clear():
    textoutput.delete(0,END)
def nine():
    textoutput.insert(END,9)
def eight():
    textoutput.insert(END,8)
def seven():
    textoutput.insert(END,7)
def six():
    textoutput.insert(END,6)
def five():
    textoutput.insert(END,5)
def four():
    textoutput.insert(END,4)
def three():
    textoutput.insert(END,3)
def two():
    textoutput.insert(END,2)
def one():
    textoutput.insert(END,1)
def zero():
    textoutput.insert(END,0)


root = Tk()
frame=Frame(root)
frame.pack()


root.title("Calculator")

num1=StringVar()

topframe=Frame(root)
topframe.pack(side=TOP)
textoutput=Entry(frame,textvariable=num1,bd=20, insertwidth=1,font=30,bg="pink")
textoutput.pack(side=TOP)

button1=Button(topframe,padx=16,pady=16,bd=6, text="7",fg="black",bg="pink",command=seven)
button1.pack(side=LEFT)
button2=Button(topframe,padx=16,pady=16,bd=6, text="8",fg="black",bg="pink",command=eight)
button2.pack(side=LEFT)
button3=Button(topframe,padx=16,pady=16,bd=6, text="9",fg="black",bg="pink",command=nine)
button3.pack(side=LEFT)
button4=Button(topframe,padx=16,pady=16,bd=6, text="-",fg="black",bg="pink",command=sub)
button4.pack(side=LEFT)

frame1=Frame(root)
frame1.pack(side=TOP)

button1=Button(frame1,padx=16,pady=16,bd=6, text="6",fg="black",bg="pink",command=six)
button1.pack(side=LEFT)
button2=Button(frame1,padx=16,pady=16,bd=6, text="5",fg="black",bg="pink",command=five)
button2.pack(side=LEFT)
button3=Button(frame1,padx=16,pady=16,bd=6, text="4",fg="black",bg="pink",command=four)
button3.pack(side=LEFT)
button4=Button(frame1,padx=16,pady=16,bd=6, text="+",fg="black",bg="pink",command=add)
button4.pack(side=LEFT)

frame2=Frame(root)
frame2.pack(side=TOP)

button1=Button(frame2,padx=16,pady=16,bd=6, text="1",fg="black",bg="pink",command=one)
button1.pack(side=LEFT)
button2=Button(frame2,padx=16,pady=16,bd=6, text="2",fg="black",bg="pink",command=two)
button2.pack(side=LEFT)
button3=Button(frame2,padx=16,pady=16,bd=6, text="3",fg="black",bg="pink",command=three)
button3.pack(side=LEFT)
button4=Button(frame2,padx=16,pady=16,bd=6, text="C",fg="black",bg="pink",command=clear)
button4.pack(side=LEFT)

frame3=Frame(root)
frame3.pack(side=TOP)

button1=Button(frame3,padx=16,pady=16,bd=6, text=temp,fg="black",bg="pink")
button1.pack(side=LEFT)
button2=Button(frame3,padx=16,pady=16,bd=6, text="0",fg="black",bg="pink",command=zero)
button2.pack(side=LEFT)
button3=Button(frame3,padx=16,pady=16,bd=6, text=total,fg="black",bg="pink")
button3.pack(side=LEFT)
button4=Button(frame3,padx=16,pady=16,bd=6, text="=",fg="black",bg="pink",command=equal)
button4.pack(side=LEFT)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: What line does the error come from?

Answer (score 2):

The error says you're running `int()` on an emty string (`''`); which obviously makes no sense to Python ...

So you want to add a check for this, at all the `int(textoutput.get())` locations, do something like:

```
def equal():
    global temp2
    value = textoutput.get()
    try:
        temp2 = int(value)
    except ValueError:
        # Show some warning that you're unable to parse this value here.
        # This error also occurs is someone filled in 'banana' or some
        # other value that can't possibly be made into an int ...
        show_warning()
        return false
    textoutput.delete(0,END)
    equalparttwo()
```

I used the `value` variable to make sure the `ValueError` is coming from
`int(value)`, and that we're not catching some other (unexpected) error from
`textoutput.get()` (this can be rather hard to debug).

The lesson here is to *never trust user input*; you're expecting a number here,
but user input can be **anything**. Always sanitize user input even for simple
purposes like a calculator, and never make assumptions about what it can and
cannot be.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is here:

```
def equalparttwo():
    # ...
    if unisymbol == 'minus':
        temp2 = int(textoutput.get())
```

At this line, `textoutput` is blank; as you have already collected the input in the caller and deleted it:

```
def equal():
    global temp2
    temp2=int(textoutput.get()) # Here you already have saved value
    textoutput.delete(0,END) # and here you have cleared it
    equalparttwo()
```

So you can delete this line `temp2 = int(textoutput.get())` in `equalparttwo()`